# Compute the number of circuit layers in an UCC type ansatz using Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, clops

I am trying to compute the number of circuit layers in a UCC ansatz in Qiskit in order to estimate the circuit running time using CLOPS estimates on IBM quantum devices. Here is what I tried to do:

```
from qiskit.transpiler import PassManager, StagedPassManager
from qiskit_nature.converters.second_quantization import QubitConverter
from qiskit_nature.second_q.circuit.library.ansatzes import UCC
from qiskit_nature.second_q.drivers import PySCFDriver
from qiskit_nature.second_q.formats.molecule_info import MoleculeInfo
from qiskit_nature.second_q.mappers import ParityMapper

qubit_converter = QubitConverter(ParityMapper(), two_qubit_reduction=True, z2symmetry_reduction='auto')

molecule = MoleculeInfo(["H", "Be", "H"], [(0., 0., -1.3264), (0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 1.3264)],)
driver = PySCFDriver.from_molecule(molecule, basis="sto3g")
electronic_structure_problem = driver.run()

second_quantized_hamiltonian = electronic_structure_problem.second_q_ops()   
pauli_sum_operator = qubit_converter.convert(second_quantized_hamiltonian[0], num_particles=electronic_structure_problem.num_particles)

num_particles = electronic_structure_problem.num_particles
num_spin_orbitals = electronic_structure_problem.num_spin_orbitals

uccsdt_ansatz = UCC(int(num_spin_orbitals/2), num_particles, excitations="sdt", qubit_converter=qubit_converter)

# more info on pass managers here: https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/transpiler.html
pm = StagedPassManager(stages=["init"])
circuit = pm.run(uccsdt_ansatz)
print(circuit.depth())
```

However, the above does not work, an exception is thrown ('ListOp' object has no attribute 'to_circuit'). Here is the qiskit version I am using: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your QubitConvertor needs importing from second_q location. If you are wanting auto symmetry reduction you need to pass the sector locator from the problem into the convert. This runs and prints a value.

```
from qiskit.transpiler import PassManager, StagedPassManager
from qiskit_nature.second_q.mappers import QubitConverter
from qiskit_nature.second_q.circuit.library.ansatzes import UCC
from qiskit_nature.second_q.drivers import PySCFDriver
from qiskit_nature.second_q.formats.molecule_info import MoleculeInfo
from qiskit_nature.second_q.mappers import ParityMapper

qubit_converter = QubitConverter(ParityMapper(), two_qubit_reduction=True, z2symmetry_reduction='auto')

molecule = MoleculeInfo(["H", "Be", "H"], [(0., 0., -1.3264), (0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 1.3264)],)
driver = PySCFDriver.from_molecule(molecule, basis="sto3g")
electronic_structure_problem = driver.run()

second_quantized_hamiltonian = electronic_structure_problem.second_q_ops()
pauli_sum_operator = qubit_converter.convert(second_quantized_hamiltonian[0], num_particles=electronic_structure_problem.num_particles, sector_locator=electronic_structure_problem.symmetry_sector_locator)

num_particles = electronic_structure_problem.num_particles
num_spatial_orbitals = electronic_structure_problem.num_spatial_orbitals

uccsdt_ansatz = UCC(num_spatial_orbitals, num_particles, excitations="sdt", qubit_converter=qubit_converter)

# more info on pass managers here: https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/transpiler.html
pm = StagedPassManager(stages=["init"])
circuit = pm.run(uccsdt_ansatz)
print(circuit.depth())
```

Answer (score 0):

In the context of CLOPS, circuit depth is calculated differently than the default behavior of `QuantumCircuit.depth()` method:

- You have to decompose your circuit into the native gate set of the backend before calculating it, and
- A 1-qubit gate from the native gate set is included if it has non-zero duration.

You can find the considerations you need to take when calculating depth in appendix of the [paper](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2110.14108) mentioned in your comment.

Comment: I don't think transpiling against a backend is what need. The notion of Circuit Layers is defined in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.14108.pdf in the context of defining the quantum volume. Please note the comment in section B on 'Quantum Volume': when a QV circuit is compiled to the native gate set of a particular QPU, the circuit depth of the compiled circuit will typically be much larger than the number of QV layers. What I want to measure is roughly the number of Circuit Layers, meaning the depth of the circuit not yet transpiled but decomposed in one and two qubit gates.

Comment: I miss read your question, sorry about that. Answer has been updated.